# JFreechart into Netbeans pallete

Tags: java, netbeans, charts, jfreechart

Recently every GUI's component that i found from other library it's very useful when i added it into the Netbeans pallete. But for this one (JFreeChart), i don't know.

This is the library i'm taking about. [JFreechart.](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/)

I already added the library into the netbeans. Just usual.
[image]

But when adding into the pallete, i found too many files. Which one should i pick? Confused.... 
[image]

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=117848).

Comment: isn't forbidden?

Comment: Not at all; just a link for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should select all files which are component classes, so if you hold [CTRL] or ([CMD] on Mac) you should be able to select multiple files. I think for JFreechart the files that end with "Chart" are the chart components.

Edit:

Actually after trying myself I just had to recognize that this is not possible, there is only one Swing Component inside JFreechart which is ChartPanel and that one isn't following the Bean-Specs, so there is no way to add JFreechart to the GUI Builder of NetBeans, you would need to place a JPanel where you want to have the chart and then create the ChartPanel manually in your code and add it then to the JPanel. Hope that helps

Comment: ooh,... that's the case. Seems the developers of jFreechart don't have any intention to make it pluggable into netbean's pallete. Sigh :(
Any other library with the similar functionality but can be included into the pallete, @funfried ?

Comment: @gumuruh I don't think so, at least I can't think of any other good charting library than JFreechart in that use case. But what would be the advantage to have it in Matisse (name of the GUI builder)? You still have to create the plots and some renderers in your code, the ChartPanel is the smallest part of a chart in JFreechart.

Comment: the benefit, is the size, and it's fixed place position after we dragged it on jframe. Just like what we used to do with JTable and its components inside. :D But, sure, we still can customized it within the code (programatically).